# How to find and copy files based on extension?

Tags: find, filenames, cp, xargs

I have a `photorec` folder from a data recovery process that has 2481 folders with the recovered files.

The folder names are in the sequence recup_dir.1, recup_dir.2 ... recup_dir.2481

I got a list of all extension in these folders with this command:

```
find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u
```

So I created another dir called `photorecorg` with a list of folders corresponding to each extension I got with the above command:

```
mkdir 7z arj asf avi bat blend bmp bz2 cdr DOC docx flac flv gif gz html jpg mobi mov mp3 mp4 mpg ods odt ogg pdf php png ppt ps psd rar rtf svg swf tar tif ttf wav wmf xcf xls xlsx xz zip
```

Now I need to copy the files in the `photorec` folder to the extension folders in `photorecorg`:

I thought in something like `find . -print | xargs cp $0 ../photorecorg/<extension>`

What would be the command that can find the files and copy to each extension dir ?

Comment: are the files in those immediate "recup" directories, or are there subdirectories within them?

Comment: the files are in the immediate recup dirs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
photorec='/pathto/your_photo_recovery_folder'
photorecorg='/pathto/your_photo_recorg_folder'

cd "$photorec" && \
   EXTDIR="$photorecorg" find . -type f -name '*.?*' -exec sh -c '
      for f
      do
         dest=${EXTDIR}/${f##*.}
         cp -p "$f" "$dest/."
      done
   ' x {} +
```

Comment: Got 1 error per file. This is one of them: `cp: cannot create regular file 'mp3/.': File or directory not found`

Comment: Did you properly initialize the `photorecorg` variable with full path? Coz this looks like `$photorecorg` is null.

Comment: it's null and I'm debugging it and seeing that all should be ok. I echoed it before the loop and it echos correctly. when I echoed it in the loop it's empty.

Comment: should be some scope issue

Comment: You are right just look at the fixed version in the answer section.My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Run [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell). Put `autoload zmv` in your `~/.zshrc` (or, to try it out, type this on the zsh command line). Then you can use the [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-mv) to move or copy files.

```
mv -Q '**/*(.)' '$f:e/$f:t'
```

Explanation: the first operand is a pattern of files to move, the second is the replacement pattern. `**/` matches files in subdirectories recursively. `(.)` is a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), it restricts the matches to regular files (so we don't risk matching directories). In the replacement pattern, `$f` designates the original path, the [modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) `e` retains only the extension, and `t` retains the full base name.

Comment: I guess I have to take a look at zsh. Advanced stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

additional to @user218374 with **mkdir -p**.

```bsh
photorec='/media/TiloDataRecoveryRAW'
photorecorg='/media//TiloDataRecoveryOrg'

cd "$photorec" && \
   EXTDIR="$photorecorg" find . -type f -name '*.?*' -exec sh -c '
      for f
      do
         dest=${EXTDIR}/${f##*.}
         mkdir -p "$dest" && cp -p "$f" "$dest/."
      done
   ' x {} +
```